# Помощь в оптимизации программы (C++)

Tags: c++, оптимизация

решал задачу (условие и тесты приложены в фото) но не знаю, как упростить решение. Если есть идеи, подскажите. Спасибо.
olympiads.ru/zaoch/2019-20/zaoch/statements-20191209.pdf (Задача В)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    long long int n,h;
    cin>>n>>h;
    char z[100000];
    long long int x[h];
    for (long long int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        cin>>z[i]>>x[i];
        if(x[i]>h || x[i]<=0)
        {
            cout<<'0'<<endl;
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    long long int counter=0;
     long long int sum=0;
    for (long long int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if(z[i]=='u')
        sum+=x[i];
        else if(z[i]=='d')
            sum-=x[i];
    }
    if(sum>h)
    {
        cout<<'0'<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
    for(long long int w=1;w<=h;)
    {
    for(long long int j=w;j<=h;j++)
    {
       long long int buf=j;
        for (long long int i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        if (j>h || j<=0) break;
        if(z[i]=='u') j+=x[i];
        if(z[i]=='d') j-=x[i];
        if (j>h) counter--;
        if (j<=0) counter--;
    }
        j=buf;
        w++;

         counter++;
    }

    }
    cout<<counter<<endl;
}
```

[image: test]

Comment: Дайте лучше URL

Comment: https://olympiads.ru/zaoch/2019-20/zaoch/statements-20191209.pdf      (Задача В)

Comment: Я не об условии, а URL, где это можно сдать и проверить :)

Comment: А `long long int x[h];` Вас не смущает?

Comment: Простите) Вот https://olympiads.ru/ej/register/reg-login-page?contest_id=252&locale_id=1

Comment: При тестировании используются большие значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это достаточно оптимизировано?...

```
int main()
{
    long long h, m = 0, M = 0, curr = 0;
    int n;
    cin >> n >> h;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        long long x; char c;
        cin >> c >> x;
        curr += c == 'd' ? -x : x;
        if (m > curr) m = curr; else if (M < curr) M = curr;
    }
    curr = h-M+m;
    cout << ((curr < 0) ? 0 : curr) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, а что означает последняя строка (где знак вопроса)?

Comment: **A ? B : C** - если **A** "истина", берется **B**. Иначе берется **C**

Comment: Т.е. если `curr` меньше нуля, вывести 0, если нет - вывести `curr`.

Comment: если **МЕНЬШЕ** - `0`, если **БОЛЬШЕ ИЛИ РАВНО** - `curr`